# Trouble getting SSL to work with NGINX in Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl

I am trying to use NGINX as a proxy with a next.js frontend and FastAPI backend, each running in their own container.

I got everything working fine with HTTP, but having some issues getting things to work with HTTPS.

All containers start running without any issues, and things seem to be working, but when I try to communicate with the proxy, I get the following errors:

```
From host:
lafton@lafton-platform:~$ curl localhost -L
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:443
```

```
Form inside NGINX container using localhost:
root@6016e75698cf:/# curl localhost -L
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'localhost'
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

```
From inside NGINX container using lafton.io:
root@6016e75698cf:/# curl https://lafton.io
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to lafton.io:443
```

I tried to install NGINX locally instead of inside Docker and it works as expected. I tried to enable the SSL configuration which is commented out in the default configuration, and it worked perfectly with SSL locally.

I then tried to use the default SSL configuration with my setup, but it does not work.
This is the NGINX config I am running inside /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  lafton.io;

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }


    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  lafton.io;

        ssl_certificate      /etc/certs/fullchain1.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/certs/privkey1.pem;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://lafton-website:3000;
        }

        location /api/albums {
            proxy_pass http://lafton-albums:8000;
        }
    }
}
```

The port 80 part is just a redirect to https. It is the exact same without it.
The ciphers is from Mozillas recommendations. I tried to change this from the default as some of the troubleshooting I did seemed to indicate no matching ciphers.

I am really lost here and not sure where to look for further troubleshooting. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: simple question: Does your container expose 443 or just 80 to the host? The `curl` from inside the container will just work with `curl -L -k` to accept non-CN-matching certs. I guess your certs CN are something with `lfton.io` but not localhost. Make sure your are accepting untrusted TLS connections with curl by adding `-k` and try it again.

Comment: This is awkward...

You are correct about the ```curl -L -k```part. It worked from inside the container as soon as I used this. Thanks for the tip!

I was sure the container exposed port 443, but I see now that I had typed 433 instead. Since I couldn't get it to work inside the container, I was so sure the problem was inside the container. 

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timo Stark's comment solved the issue.

It didn't work inside the container because the certificates CN was lafton.io, so I had to use the `-k` flag in the curl command.
When that worked, I saw a typo in my docker-compose file, so the container had exposed port 433, not 443.